# Eliminate X-Axis Gaps in ggplot Line Chart

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, linechart

When I create a line chart with ggplot, two gaps appear on either side of the x-axis, as can be seen below:

[image]

How can I prevent this so that the line starts and ends at both edges of the x-axis, rather than just before/after?

Here is the code I far so far:

```
germany_yields <- read.csv(file = "Germany 10-Year Yield Weekly (2007-2020).csv", stringsAsFactors = F)
italy_yields <- read.csv(file = "Italy 10-Year Yield Weekly (2007-2020).csv", stringsAsFactors = F)

germany_yields <- germany_yields[, -(3:6)]
italy_yields <- italy_yields[, -(3:6)]

colnames(germany_yields)[1] <- "Date"
colnames(germany_yields)[2] <- "Germany.Yield"
colnames(italy_yields)[1] <- "Date"
colnames(italy_yields)[2] <- "Italy.Yield"

combined <- join(germany_yields, italy_yields, by = "Date")
combined <- na.omit(combined)
combined$Date <- as.Date(combined$Date,format = "%B %d, %Y")
combined["Spread"] <- combined$Italy.Yield - combined$Germany.Yield

ggplot(data=combined, aes(x = Date, y = Spread)) + geom_line()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `expand=` argument from any `scale_` ggplot command to adjust the buffer between the `limits` of the scale and the edge of the plot area.

Example:

```
df <- data.frame(x=1:100, y=rnorm(100))
ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + geom_line() + xlim(0,100)
```

You still have the edges on the x axis:

[image]

But add the `expand` argument to specify how much to expand past the edges of the `limits`.  Note that the argument expects *two* values, so you can specify how far to expand past the upper and lower limits:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + geom_line() + scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0,100), expand=c(0,0))
```

[image]